# What does the . (dot) mean in ~replace_na(., 0)

Tags: r, tidyverse, na, dplyr

new to R and coding.

I've got a data frame with +- 1000 observations and +- 100 variables. I would like to replace the NA values with 0 (zero) in selected columns (var1, var2, var5, var6).

After reading a few other posts about this subject, I came to this code, which replaces the NA's successfully.

`df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(var1, var2, var5, var6), ~replace_na(., 0))`

Now I understand most of the code, expect the . (dot) in: `~replace_na(., 0))`

What does the . (dot) exactly mean in this function?

Comment: Dot represents `all data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one-sided formula is called a lambda-function.

It is a faster way to write simple anonymous functions, using the internal variable as `.` or `.x`. I personally prefer `.x`, as `.` is already used by `dplyr` as the left-hand variable of the pipe, which might cause confusion.

In this context (inside `mutate_at`), `~replace_na(., 0))` and `~replace_na(.x, 0))` are the same as `function(x) replace_na(x, 0)`.

You can try this with the same result:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(var1, var2, var5, var6), function(x) replace_na(x, 0))
```

Besides, please note that `mutate_at` is deprecated as for `dplyr 1.0`. You might want to use the new syntax with the `across` function:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(var1, var2, var5, var6), ~replace_na(.x, 0)))
```